# Why can't Newton's method be used directly for square roots?

Tags: radicals, newton-raphson

If I want to use Newton's method for a polynomial function I simply use the definition and derive it to get to the fraction which needs to be deducted from the current guess. For instance, if $f(x)= x^3 - x - 1$, then I have $f'(x) = 3 x^2 - 1$.

Why can't I use $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$? I noticed that $\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}$ gives me $-x$, which would not converge.

Thanks.

Comment: See Overshoot in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method.  This is exactly the example discussed.

Answer (score 1):

To overcome this inconvenience you can use a trick:

$$
f(x) := \lambda\sqrt{x} + (1-\lambda)(x-x_0)
$$

where chosen a sufficiently large $n \in \mathbb{N}$:

$$
\lambda = \frac{k}{n},
\quad \quad \quad
x_k = x_{k-1} - \frac{f(x_{k-1})}{f'(x_{k-1})}
$$

with $k=1,2,\dots,n$.